# Laravel email template URLs not working in Gmail

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, gmail, html-email

I am using Laravel 4 smtp mail to send mail to users. When I send mails to Gmail, the logo and URLs didn't show up as intended. When I checked the urls, it showed localhost instead of my domain name. I don't know why it's happening.

**My email template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            color: #333;
        }
        #table-wrap {
            background:#fafafa;
            border-bottom: 5px solid #eee;
            border-top: 5px solid #EC4F48;
        }
        #site_logo{
            background: #EC4F48; 
            border-bottom: 2px solid #EC4F48;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
        }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table-wrap" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="padding:3px; border-bottom: 2px solid #fadc65;" width="60%">
                        <h3 style="margin-left: 15px;">Hi, {{{ $username }}}!</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" id="site_logo">
                        <img src="{{ asset('dist/img/logo.png') }}" width="200" style="margin-left: 10px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <br />
                            <h2>Welcome to mydomain.com !</h2>
                            <h2>Thanks for registering to Mysite.</h2>
                            <h4><a href="{{ url('user/verify/'.$code) }}" target="_blank">Click here to confirm your email...</a></h4>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <p style="margin-left: 20px; color: #666;">
                         www.mydomain.com&nbsp; | &nbsp;Email : feedback@mydomain.com
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use CLI to send this email or its triggered in browser?

Comment: @l3ehnam yes its CLI. I made a work around for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use CLI to generate any view Laravel uses `url` parameter to set domain. By default its value is set to `http://localhost` so you need to change this parameter to your domain.

The parameter is located in `app.php` in `config` folder.

Laravel comment for Application URL:
`This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.`

Comment: This is not the answer